# Git push existing local repo to new remote branch when no changes are detected

Tags: git, github, server, bitbucket, remote-server

First off I made a mistake when creating the project: got it working, and then did my `git init` after many changes, so git doesn't detect any changes when pushing source code to my remote repo. I do have working .gitignore files.

When I try to push to master now of course no changes are detected. I can do a force add which then overrides my .gitignore files and adds everything which I **DONT** want.

Whats the best way to fix my issue?

Comment: Sounds like you had an existing git repo stored somewhere, but then 'created a project'. How did you create the project? (Typically you would do a `git clone`, which would leave you with a local clone of the git repo and no need to perform a subsequent `git init`.) 
And to clarify, are you saying you have `.gitignore` files in the remote repo, but want to maintain a separate set of `.gitignore` files in your local repo?

Comment: Do you have a remote repo with changes that are the same as seen on your local repo? Even if you add git midway, you'll have to add them to `git tracking` if they are un-tracked. Only tracked files can be committed. If they don't have any changes (the tracked files) then there's nothing to be committed.

Comment: I started out with a fresh laravel install via composer create-project   this comes with its own .gitignore files   .  Then I made some changes got some functionality working, and THEN I did git init.  So now I just want to know the best way to properly push my working local project to bitbucket.